# Ionic 2 file transfer with additional data

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to send file to the api using ionic 2 file transfer along with additional parameters. It is form data. Here is the function where I am sending the data to the api end:

```
 uploadFileRemark(businessId,theFile,content,val){
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    console.log(theFile);
    var uploadOptions = {
      fileKey: "img_url",
      fileName: "img.png",
      params : {'bid':businessId,"imgurl":theFile,"content":content},      
      headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + val, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    };

    //console.log(this.api.url+'/api/business/postRemark');
    this.createLoadingSpinner();
    this.presentLoadingSpinner();
    let ft = fileTransfer.upload(theFile,this.api.url+'/api/business/postRemark', uploadOptions)
    .then((data) => {
      this.dismissLoadingSpinner();      
      console.log(data);
      alert("BID"+businessId+" "+JSON.stringify(data));
    }, (err) => { 
      this.dismissLoadingSpinner();
      console.log('OOPS!!! UNSUCCESSFUL');
      alert("BID"+businessId+" "+JSON.stringify(err));

    })
    return ft;
  }
```

But it gives me the same response if I send the request through postman without the "bid" parameter. I have checked the variable format and others. But, it still does not work. What went wrong.

Comment: Did you try with removing header `Content-Type` ? because you are sending mulipart formdata so header `Content-Type` shouldn't be `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: I did. I used this 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' out of frustration.. :). Have no idea whats going on.. :(

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't how you handle this request in back end side but this code looks fine except content-type header and did it worked from post man ?

Comment: There is no issue with the backend. In whichever format I send the parameters from the frontend it hits on the backend and gives a response which I will get If I didn't fill up the form field (bid) in postman. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change file transfer upload options:

```
var uploadOptions = {
      fileKey: "file", // change fileKey
      chunkedMode: false, // add chunkedMode
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data", // add mimeType
      fileName: "img.png",
      params : {'bid':businessId,"imgurl":theFile,"content":content},      
      headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + val, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    };
```

Comment: Did try with this earlier. Didn't work. I think it's an issue with the plugin.